# Site is continuously loading, when we add SMTP Server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, smtpclient

I have created one php file and in that file i'm sending emails to a users who have done donations. (Donations it's just an example)

when user submit a donation and fill the form then the site is continuously loading. not even showing the errors.

but it's not showing any emails and not even the errors but site is loading continuously.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wp-load.php");
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/wp-content/plugins/project-funders/assets/smtp/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

global $wpdb;
$settingsTable = $wpdb->prefix . "flight_funders_settings";
$settings = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM $settingsTable"
);

$emails = [];
$flightId = $_POST['flight_id'];
$prayerTable = $wpdb->prefix . "flight_funders_prayer_donations";
$moneyTable = $wpdb->prefix . "flight_funders_money_donations";
$prayers = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM $prayerTable WHERE `flight_id`= $flightId"
);
$moneys = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT * FROM $moneyTable WHERE `flight_id`= $flightId"
);
foreach($prayers as $prayer){
    $emails[] = $prayer->donator_email;
}

foreach($moneys as $money){
    $emails[] = $money->donator_email;
}

unset($_POST["flight_id"]);
$emailDatas = [];
foreach($_POST as $emailData){
    $emailDatas[] = $emailData;
}

$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Host = $settings[7]->settings_value;
$mail->Port = $settings[8]->settings_value; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username = $settings[9]->settings_value;
$mail->Password = $settings[10]->settings_value;
$mail->SetFrom($settings[9]->settings_value);
$mail->Subject = $emailDatas[0];
$mail->Body = $emailDatas[1];
$mail->addBCC($settings[9]->settings_value);
foreach($emails as $email){
    $mail->addBCC($email);
}
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Sorry";
}
else{
    $flightTable = $wpdb->prefix . "flight_funders_flights";
    $flights = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT * FROM $flightTable WHERE `flight_id`=$flightId"
    )[0];
    $flight_title = $flights->flight_title;
    $notificationTable = $wpdb->prefix . "flight_funders_notifications";
    $insertNotification = $wpdb->query(
        "INSERT INTO $notificationTable (`flight_title`, `notification_subject`, `notification_message`) VALUES ('$flight_title','$emailDatas[0]','$emailDatas[1]')"
    );
    echo "Sent";
}
?>
```

How can i solve that?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like PHP is busy sending the mail and for some reason it is taking a long time (or not working). Check the SMTP settings?

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection attack, so you need to read up on how to fix that. Beyond that, it’s likely your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, and you’re falling into the 10-minute SMTP timeout. Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide for more about how to diagnose this.